# How to show image in web page which came response of api ( computer vision - thumbnil service in azure ) in node js

Tags: node.js, image, azure, api, azure-cognitive-services

**This is response come from api**

```
apim-request-id: a6ac620f-8484-4bdf-a9ed-d26080186769
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 09:10:23 GMT
Content-Length: 49368
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

**Here,The code of call api**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app).listen(8080);
const fs=require("fs");
const request = require('request');

// Replace <Subscription Key> with your valid subscription key.
const subscriptionKey = 'key';

const uriBase =
    'https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/generateThumbnail';

const imageUrl =
    'https://smworld.co.in/images/bg1.jpg';

// Request parameters.
const params = {
    'width': '300',
    'height': '300',
    'smartCropping': 'true'
};

const options = {
    uri: uriBase,
    qs: params,
    body: '{"url": ' + '"' + imageUrl + '"}',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey
    }
};
```

Comment: You can possibly convert response bytes to base64 and return an image tag in the HTML page that contains the image data as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html).

Comment: it's not working

Comment: @AbhiSavadiya The description of your question is too simple, I don't know how to help you. Could you post more details about your title, and post some necessary code in NodeJS? Please refer to the SO help topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to update your post. Thanks.

Comment: @peterpan now see is this okay ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to test the solution in @Wiktor Zychla comment, but it only works for `png` image, not `jpeg`. So I tried to give my solution to embed an image url into a static html content.

Here is my sample code as reference for you.

```
var request = require('request');

const subscriptionKey = 'key';

const uriBase = 'https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/generateThumbnail';

const imageUrl = 'https://smworld.co.in/images/bg1.jpg';

// Request parameters.
const params = {
    'width': '300',
    'height': '300',
    'smartCropping': 'true'
};

const options = {
    uri: uriBase,
    qs: params,
    body: '{"url": ' + '"' + imageUrl + '"}',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey
    }
};

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/img', function(req, res) {
    request.post(options).pipe(res)
})

// embed an image url `/img` into the html code
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        var html = '<h2>Hello world</h2></br><img src="/img"/>'
        res.send(html)

})

app.listen(3000)
```

The result of the above code as below run on my local env.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you explain this line of code                                                                                                        request.post(options).pipe(res)

Comment: @AbhiSavadiya Please refer to https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming. Just pipe write the stream of the request response of cognitive api to express response.

Comment: Thakyou @peterpan